# what ist the differences betwenn function and methode

Tags: function, methods

what ist the differences betwenn function and methode?!

is that different for every programming language?
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: This is the same question but only for oop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function but there are also answeres which consider other not oo languages. Please use the search function before asking a question which might already be answered here on stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a method and a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)

Comment: thx bro...........